# I want to extract any digits contains the specific years

Tags: r

For example, i have the following data.

```
ID
74019559952254665
74019229952254665
74019889952254665
74020209952254665
74020229952254665
```

i want to extract any digit contains the year from 1922 to 2022, please note that the starting number for any digit is fixed 740 and the forth numbers after it is the year of birth and the rest of number is a random numbers.
for example if i have the ID 74018509952254665 should be ignored, because 1850 not in my range.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `ID` column to be integers which would always have the same width of 17 digits, we can use integer division and the modulus here:

```r
df[((df$ID %/% 10000000000) %% 10000) %in% c(1922:2002), ]
```

Notes:

The `%/%` is the integer division operator.  As used above, it will effectively truncate off the last 10 digits, leaving behind the year in the last 4 digits.

The `%%` is R's modulus operator.  As used here, it will give the remainder of the above 7 digit number when divided by 10000, which is just the 4 digit year.

If your `ID` column be numeric *and* it really has fixed width, then the approach in my answer should outperform a string approach.  This is because a few small arithmetic operations are much less costly than creating a string and then performing a substring or regex operation.

Comment: This is lovely.  Can I check I'm understanding it correctly? `%/% 10000000000` effectively drops the last 10 digits, whereas the `%% 10000` effectively discards all but the last four digits?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract by position with `substr`, and then filter the appropriate years.

```
df[as.numeric(substr(df$ID, 4, 7)) %in% 1922:2022, , drop = FALSE]

#                  ID
# 1 74019559952254672
# 2 74019229952254672
# 3 74019889952254672
# 4 74020209952254672
# 5 74020229952254672
```

Comment: i want to ignore any ID not start with 740 and then extract the first 10 digits

Comment: You can create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of years and then use `str_detect()` to look for them

```
library(tidyverse)

years <- paste0(seq(1922, 2022, by = 1), collapse = "|")

df %>% 
  mutate(show = ifelse(str_detect(ID, years), ID, " "))
```